# (In resumes,) How to break a long long sentence into two lines?

Tags: tables, resume

```
\begin{rSection}{Skills}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }

Languages: \ & Java/J2EE, ... \\

Frameworks: \ & Struts, Spring, Hibernate, Spring MVC, Spring Boot, Spring Data, Spring Batch, Spring Cloud, Spring boot, Spring JDBC, Spring IOC, Spring Security \\




\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}
```

[image]

[image]

I'm using Overleaf to edit my draft resume.

How do you split the long sentence into two or more lines in this situation?

Thanks in advance for answering!

[image: Somehow it starts as a new page after the modification]

Comment: `\usepackage{array}` in your preamble and `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}` instead of your last `l` column type

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @koleygr I added `\usepackage{array}` in the preamble and changed the second line to `\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm} l}` It didn't work out. What did I do wrong in this case? Thanks for any help as I'm pretty new to LaTeX.

Comment: change the last `l` not the first one!

Comment: Thank you so much! It did the job and I changed 5cm to 11cm so it fits on the page. Would you mind also looking at the new screenshot I added at the end of the question? How would you avoid the new page in this case? I tried to add `\nopagebreak` but didn't help.

Comment: Add a `\newpage` command before the section command that is in the previous page, or reduce the font size or (reduce) the `\parskip` length

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you (a) load the `tabularx` and `ragged2e` packages, (b) employ a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and (c) use ragged-right layout rather than full justification in the second column. I.e., something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l >{\RaggedRight}X @{} }
Languages 
& Java/J2EE, \dots \\

Frameworks  
& Struts, Spring, Hibernate, Spring MVC, Spring Boot, Spring Data, 
  Spring Batch, Spring Cloud, Spring boot, Spring JDBC, Spring IOC, 
  Spring Security 

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```